# How to join a query result with a value, received from another query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rsk, rootstock

I want to calculate transaction costs in USD
for a number of most recent transactions
on the [Rootstock](https://developers.rsk.co/) blockchain.
I have a PostgreSQL database table with token
prices `reports.token_prices`
from which I select the **value**
of the latest available RBTC price in USD:

```sql
select tp.price_in_usd  
from reports.token_prices tp
where tp.chain_id = 30 
and tp.coingecko_token_id = 'rootstock'
order by tp.dt desc
limit 1
```

(note that `tp.dt` is a timestamp)

Result of the query:

```
16995.771
```

Then I have a table with all transactions,
`chain_rsk_mainnet.block_transactions`,
from which I select the gas fees
for the 5 most recent ones:

```sql
select
bt.fees_paid
from chain_rsk_mainnet.block_transactions bt
order by bt.block_id desc, bt.tx_offset 
limit 5
```

(note that instead of using a timestamp, I'm using `bt.block_id` and `bt.tx_offset` for transaction order)

Result:

```
0
4469416300800
4469416300800
16450260000000
0
```

Now I want to multiply each of these numbers
by the result of the first query.
How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: sample data please.  It's not easy to work up a fiddle without that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I already received a perfect solution from Belayer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without further information your simplest option would be just convert the first query into a CTE then Join that result in the second query.

```
with  price_cte(price_in_usd) as 
      (select tp.price_in_usd  
         from reports.token_prices tp
        where tp.chain_id = 30 
          and tp.coingecko_token_id = 'rootstock'
        order by tp.dt desc
        limit 1
      )
select bt.fees_paid * p.price_in_usd)  "Fees Paid in USD"
  from chain_rsk_mainnet.block_transactions bt
  cross join price_cte p
 order by bt.block_id desc, bt.tx_offset 
 limit 5;
```

**NOTE:** Not tested, no sample data nor results.

Comment: wow, that's amazing! So elegant and compact! I tried and it worked. Thanks a lot!